# javascript function is called before dropdown value is set

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a dropdown list in a gridview template field and passing the rowIndex to a javascript function.  It seems like the javascript function is fired before the value on the dropdown has time to fully change to the selected value.  Consequently I'm always getting the first index returned even though I selected otherwise from the dropdown...

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Establishment">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="drpUserEstablishment" CssClass="dropdown" ClientIDMode="Static"
                                runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"
                                onchange='<%#"setUserEstablishment(" + Container.DataItemIndex +")"%>'>
                            </asp:DropDownList>

                       </ItemTemplate>

  </asp:TemplateField>
```

Javascript function:

```
function setUserEstablishment(rowIndex) {
     var establishid = $('#drpUserEstablishment option:selected').val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

passing "this" and then using this in the function seems to resolve this one

```
onchange='<%#"test(" + "this"+","+Container.DataItemIndex +")"%>'

 function test(ddl,rowindex) {

                                      var index = ddl.selectedIndex;

                                      alert("rowindex=" + rowindex);

                                      alert('Selected Value = ' + ddl.value + '\r\nSelected Index = ' + index);
}
```